# Make R Markdown table borders visible after kniting to .doc

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I have table defined like that

````
```{r results='asis'}
library(Ryacas)
library(pander)
m<-rbind(c("x","x^2"),c("y","y^2"))
Apycs<-function(m){
  library(Ryacas)
  m1<-m 
  for (k in 1:nrow(m)){ for (l in 1:ncol(m)){
    m.2<-yacas(TeXForm(m[k,l]))[[2]]
    m1[k,l]<-substr(m.2,2,nchar(m.2)-2)}}
  return(m1)}
m<-Apycs(m)
pandoc.table(m, style="grid")

```
````

How to make lines that separate table cells visible  (print preview in .doc) 
 file without doing it manually ?

Comment: The style of fonts, paragraphs depend on the provided `--reference-docx` style reference, which *might* have an effect on the resulting tables as well -- but I doubt it: http://pandoc.org/README.html#options-affecting-specific-writers

Comment: There was a [feature request](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pandoc-discuss/jcv728kfXCA/UOMyne3sYhkJ) on the pandoc mailing list in 2012 but it has never been implemented. See pandoc's [release notes](http://pandoc.org/releases.html).

Answer (score -1):

It will involve two steps and both require the [kableExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/kableExtra.pdf) package and none requires **pander package**. Keep everything the same till the code below:

```
pandoc.table(m, style="grid")
```

In the 1st step: Create a LaTeX table with borders keeping booktabs FALSE and making use of **kable_styling** form kableExtra. Convert the LaTeX table to an image with **kable_as_image** form kableExtra to be used in an rmarkdown document in the 2nd step. Then knit it to pdf. As indicated [kableExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/kableExtra.pdf) package this is a "better than nothing" solution to print high quality tables in rmarkdown Word document.

````
```{r results='asis'}
library(kableExtra)
library(Ryacas)

m<-rbind(c("x","x^2"),c("y","y^2"))
Apycs<-function(m){
m1<-m
for (k in 1:nrow(m)){ for (l in 1:ncol(m)){
m.2<-yacas(TeXForm(m[k,l]))[[2]]
m1[k,l]<-substr(m.2,2,nchar(m.2)-2)}}
return(m1)}
m<-Apycs(m)

knitr::kable(m, "latex", booktabs = F) %>%
       column_spec(1, border_left = T) %>%
       column_spec(2, border_right = T) %>%
       kable_as_image("my_latex_table")

```
````

Note that **kable_as_image** is a LaTeX-only function and this feature requires you to have magick installed (install.packages("magick")). In addition to that, if you are planning to use it on a Windows computer, you need to install Ghostscript.

The output we are after is called **my_latex_table.png** and can be found where your working directory is.

In the 2nd step: we simply include **my_latex_table.png** in the .Rmd file to be knitted to .doc

```
![Bordered Table](my_latex_table.png)
```